# Update query schemaRDD

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am using schemaRDD in scala for some data transformations. When using update query just like SQL context like this example `UPDATE users SET email = 'abc@example.com' WHERE ID = 1` I  get the following error :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ''UNCACHE'' expected but identifier UPDATE found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the underlying implementation (data structure) of a SchemaRDD is an RDD which is immutable, I don't think it supports an UPDATE. If you want to update something, one way is to create a copy and do the transformation there and save the updated set to your datastore.

Comment: Can you explain better how you could do that? Posting some code will be appreciated.Thanks